# Detect battery discharging and send SMS

Tags: charging

As solution for a problem at work, I need to find a way to send a SMS to a list of numbers if the mobile discharges for 1 minute or more

So is there any recommendation on how to achieve this?

Comment: 1.App recommendations are off topic here, so edited your question . If you are unhappy with edit, please feel free to revert changes 2. Is it time based or percentage drop in battery? 3. Your need is a little sketchily described IMO, may help to describe more

Comment: @beeshyams There is ways. Lots of ways. A tasker profile or a half decent antivirus will do the trick.

Comment: @DanB: Yes I know.  But to present a solution problem needs to be  clear.  For instance, how does the phone discharge-because of charger being disconnected or charger is connected but an application is running causing drain? This is one example that can change the trigger for macro to act

Comment: @beeshyams True true. Hmmm... I wouldnt be suprised if OP asked for something that fitted into both, tbh.